# Integration Test with Spring Cloud Config Server

Tags: spring, integration-testing, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-config-server

It's my first time implementing a Spring application using Spring Cloud Config framework. The application is working fine, getting configuration properties from repository through the server application. So, at the moment I must write the integration tests to test connection between client application and server and repository. To do it I mean get a value from repository over properties and check the value, also make a request to the server, or if exists, other method inside spring cloud config library to make it.

The problem now, when executing the integrationTest the application can't read the properties from remote. I've created a `bootstrap.yml` on the integrationTest context but not works. So, I got the errors like: `Could not resolve placeholder`.

**MyIntegrationTest**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest()
@ActiveProfiles("integrationTest")
public class MyIntegrationTest {

    @Value("${throttling.request.rate.minute}")
    private int MAX_REQUEST_PER_MINUTE;

    @Test
    public void validateGetRequestRateLimitFromRepository() {
        Assert.assertNotEquals(MAX_REQUEST_PER_MINUTE,1L);
    }


}
```

**bootstrap.yml**

```
spring:
  application:
    name: sample-name
---
spring:
  profiles: local #also tried integrationTest
  cloud:
    config:
      enabled: true
      uri: https://endpoint-uri:443
      skipSslValidation: true
      name: ${spring.application.name},${spring.application.name}-${spring.profiles}
```

Also tried:

1. Set `application-integrationTest.yml`
2. Set `application.yml`
3. Set `bootstrap-integrationTest.yml`
4. Create a `*-integrationTest.yml` at the repo.
5. Set `@ActiveProfiles("local")` on integrationTest class.

Nothing works.

Comment: See https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/blob/master/spring-cloud-config-sample/src/test/java/sample/ApplicationTests.java

Comment: `ConfigServerTestUtils.prepareLocalRepo` sounds that get a local repo.

Comment: @spencergibb thanks. it helped a lot. I found a lot of goodies within the tests :)